# How to detect url change in WebChromeClient

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I want to detect url change when redirection happens in WebView during google authentification. problem is that google restricts using WebView for authentification so i am using  WebChromeClient. 
WebChromeClient does not have ShouldOverrideUrlLoading method. I have tried to override OnReceivedTitle method but it does not detect url change. Can someone help?

```
 class CustomWebViewClient : WebChromeClient
    {
       public string Url { get; private set; }

        public override void OnReceivedTitle(WebView view, string title)
        {
            base.OnReceivedTitle(view, title);
            Url = view.Url;
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Google restricted requesting login for oAuth from webview.But In my case, my request is the custom oAuth Provider.I think and assume, you want to detect url eg: oAuth callback to webview is a messey case just seeing in a webview.I solved like that in my case:

```
@Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Timber.e("WEBVIEW %s", url);
    if(weHaveReceivedAnOAuthCallback(url)){
      view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      String reply = retrieveParamaters(url);
      oAuthCallbackListener.onOAuthCallback(reply);
    }
    if (url.startsWith("http") || url.startsWith("https")) {
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  }

  private static boolean weHaveReceivedAnOAuthCallback(String url) {
    return url.startsWith(BuildConfig.API_OAUTH_REDIRECT);
  }

  private static String retrieveParamaters(String url) {
    return url.replace(BuildConfig.API_OAUTH_REDIRECT, "");
  };
```

I hope this may help for your issue.